# Building a library refering to a library in a subdirectory using cmake

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to convert a build using Makefile that currently works for Unix and Windows. I have the following directory layout:

- lib1
- lib2

lib2 depends on lib1.

In lib1, I create on Unix a .o file using

```
ld -r obj1.o -o lib1.o'.
```

And in lib2, I also create a .o file using the lib1.o file created in the lib1 directory using:

```
ld -r obj2.o ../lib1/lib1.o -o lib2.o
```

On Windows it is very similar except we are creating a .lib file using the lib command in lib1:

```
lib -out:lib1.lib obj1.obj
```

and in lib2:

```
lib -out:lib2.lib obj2.obj ..\lib1\lib1.lib
```

Unfortunately, whatever I do, the lib1.o object file never appears when building lib2.o.

My CMakeLists.txt files are in lib1:

```
project (lib1)
add_library(lib1 obj1.c)
```

in lib2:

```
project (lib2)
add_library(lib2 obj2.c)
target_link_libraries(lib2 lib1)
```

and at the root I have:

```
project (root)
add_subdirectory(lib1)
add_subdirectory(lib2)
add_dependencies(lib2 lib1)
```

Is there something I'm missing to achieve this?

Thanks,
Manu

Comment: You need `target_link_libraries()` instead of `add_dependencies()`.

Comment: Which I do for `lib2' but it does not seem to have an effect at all.

Comment: This should work fine.  Have you tried creating the minimal example above?  There may be a difference between what you actually have and what you're showing here?